# Laravel. $fillable is not working in polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm using a more complex solution with trait, but I'll try to simplify it now.

I have such a polymorphic relation:

```
class Attraction extends Model
{

   /**
    * Get the coordinate of this object.
    */
    public function coordinate()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Coordinate::class, 'object');
    }
}


class Coordinate extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the object of this coordinate.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function object()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and in controller I'm trying to update it in such a way

```
$attraction->coordinate()->update($request->all());
```

and receive such an error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'...
```

basically, it's ignoring `$fillable` and is trying to update from all the data I've passed via `$request->all()`.

Do I miss something? If not, I'll update my example to a not simplified version, but...it's basically a "Geocodable" trait in `Attraction` model, nothing, that should change the behavior of `update()`.